# IComparable Implementation - Comparison Operator Overloading

Tags: c#

I'm studying the above mentioned and something interesting happened. To overload the comparison operators `<` and `>` I have to implement the `CompareTo` method from the `IComparable` interface. This method takes one parameter of type `object`, but in the example from the book I'm using, it wrote the method with a custom `Point` type, like so:

```
public int CompareTo(Point other) {
    if (this.X > other.X && this.Y > other.Y)
        return 1;
    if (this.X < other.X && this.Y < other.Y)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

When I write this in visual studio, the compiler says that the `IComparable` interface was not implemented.
Thinking that te problem was that the parameter passed was of `Point type`, I passed the `object type` and casted it to a `Point type` in the body of the method and it worked, like so:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    Point other = (Point)obj;
    if (this.X > other.X && this.Y > other.Y)
        return 1;
    if (this.X < other.X && this.Y < other.Y)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The book doesn´t mention anything about this. My question is: will this casting always be necessary in order for a Interface to be considered as implemented by the compiler? Or is the a more "direct" way of doing this?

Comment: there are two types of `IComparable` the generic and non-generic, depending on which you implement then different parameters are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two versions of `IComparable`. The generic and the non-generic. Both are under the `System` namespace. When you implement the non-generic `IComparable` version, the method you need to provide on your type is:

```
int CompareTo(object obj)
```

insted of the signture for generic `IComparable<T>` version:

```
int CompareTo(T obj)
```

So, in the non-generic `IComparable`, you need to cast this `obj` because it is boxed to `object`. To make sure you pass the right type, you could try a safecast, for sample:

```
if (obj == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException("The obj must be provided");

var anotherCustomer = obj as Customer;
if (anotherCustomer == null)
   throw new ArgumentException("The obj must be a Customer");
```

On the other hand, you have the generic version which is appropriated to cases when you want a specific type.

Comment: It is also good to add `if (obj == null) return 1;` in non-generic version.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Felipe! ;)